# Why are column having no leading entry are called free variable?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the textbook that I am following, it says that column with leading entry are basic variable and column that has no leading entry are called free variable. I don't get the intuition behind why are they called free variable if they don't have leading entry. Suppose, I have a system of linear equation written as augmented matrix. Reducing that matrix to row reduced echelon form, I have
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6 & 0 & 3 & 0 :& 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 0 : & 5\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 : & 7
\end{bmatrix}
Now the system can be written as,
$$
x_1+6x_2+3x_4 = 0\\
x_3-4x_4 = 5\\
x_5 = 7
$$
Now the text book says $x_1 , x_3, x_5$ are basic variable and can be expressed in terms of $x_2$ and $x_4$
$$
x_1 = -6x_2 - 3x_4\\
x_3 = 5 + 4x_4\\
x_5 = 7
$$
Why cannot I express $x_2$ in terms of $x_1$ and $x_4$ and say $x_1$ and $x_4$ are free variable.
$$x_2 = \frac{-3x_4-x_1}{6}$$

Comment: Use a better textbook that does not confuse you with such nonsense.

Comment: @KurtG. That's kindof unhelpful if this is the textbook their course is using, the book where all the weekly exercises will come from, and the book they expect you to know when the time comes for exams. It is also unhelpful if it's the one book they have managed to aquire (not everyone can get their hands on a bunch of different linear algebra textbooks just because they want a decent selection).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The point of choosing $x_2$ and $x_4$ is that when you reduce to echelon form you are certain that the variables with zero leading entry can be chosen as free parameters. In general, in a system like yours (say 3 independent equations with 5 variables) not every pair of variables can be chosen as free.